# Similarities between Proto-Austronesian and Chinese?

Tags: historical-linguistics, chinese, language-families, austronesian

Proto-Austronesian was a language that was spoken about 5,000 years ago near Taiwan. I am just curious about, partly because of the geographic connection, if Chinese is related to the Austronesian language family. Has there ever been a genetic relationship proposed between Austronesian languages and Chinese? My guess is that the language family was last in China around 4,000 BC/BCE.

Note: Austronesian languages started in Taiwan and now range from Madagascar to Easter Island.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, Chinese is not an isolated language, but a member of the well-established [Sino-Tibetan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Tibetan_languages) language family. Relationships beyond Sino-Tibetan aren't well established although the Tai-Kaddai language or the Hmong-Mien languages are included in some proposals of a larger Sino-Tibetan family.

[Sino-Austronesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Austronesian_languages) was indeed proposed by some linguists (Sagart and Starosta, with different proposals). However, it is not accepted as a valid and established grouping, and similarities between Chinese and Austronesian languages are more often traced to an Austronesian substrate in Chinese (cf. Vovin).